# FFmpeg output file format with no extension

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I'm developing a system which needs to store videos in the form:

```
/path/to/video/<md5 of the file>
```

So I do not have an output extension.
I'm using `ffmpeg` to convert those videos, but it seems that it uses output file extension to determine the output format, so here's my problem.

Due to the fact I don't have an output extension in file names, is there a way to specify the output format directly in the command line without create temporary files or dirty solutions like this ?

Comment: Might also want to use -y to allow overwriting the destination file. If you don't specify -y and the file is in use, ffmpeg will sit waiting for user input. This effectively hangs the process, as I recently discovered. :P

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use the `-f` parameter to tell ffmpeg which output-format to use. E.g

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg ... -f mp4 output
```

to create a file named `output` in mp4 format.

Comment: -f is ALSO used as input format specification, depending on position:

    ffmpeg -f mpg -i input.mpg ... -f mp4 output.mp4

Comment: Note that the question was _"what if I don't have an extension?"_ so your answer should say `output` and not `output.mp4` to prove that it works as per OP's question.

Comment: This helped me figure out my issue as well with streaming to YouTube.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67943834/ffmpeg-stream-windows-7-desktop-to-youtube-give-invalid-argument

Answer (score 1):

Same solution with [@luukes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9869165/117259) but please notice that if you're making `aac` output, the parameter for `-f` is `adts`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg ... -f adts output
```

To create a file named output in `aac` format.