# How to compress video to target size by Python?

Tags: python, video-compression

I am uploading text and videos to a site by Python program. This site says they only receive video files of up to 50 MB in size. Otherwise, they will reject the video and other associated information.

To ensure I can send video continuously, I want to compress it **to target size** (e.g. 50 MB) before sending. Because no loss of quality is impossible, it is ok to have moderate clarity loss in video or audio.

Is there any elegant way in Python for this purpose? Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Compress video files by Python and FFmpeg

### Tools

[FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) is a powerful tool for video editing. And there is a great Python binding named [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) ([API Reference](https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/)) for this. Firstly, `pip install ffmpeg-python` and [install FFmpeg](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/issues/251).

### Steps

Probe the configuration of video by function `ffmpeg.probe()` to get duration, audio & video bit rate and so on. And calculate the bit rate of the target file based on what we have. Then, construct commands by `ffmpeg.input()` and `ffmpeg.output()`. Finally, run it.

### Codes

Following is the example code. Change the compression algo for your situation if you want. For easy follow-up, I hided the code of boundary condition. The code I am using is in [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/ESWZY/a420a308d3118f21274a0bc3a6feb1ff). Any bug report is welcomed!

```py
import os, ffmpeg
def compress_video(video_full_path, output_file_name, target_size):
    # Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rate#Encoding_bit_rate
    min_audio_bitrate = 32000
    max_audio_bitrate = 256000

    probe = ffmpeg.probe(video_full_path)
    # Video duration, in s.
    duration = float(probe['format']['duration'])
    # Audio bitrate, in bps.
    audio_bitrate = float(next((s for s in probe['streams'] if s['codec_type'] == 'audio'), None)['bit_rate'])
    # Target total bitrate, in bps.
    target_total_bitrate = (target_size * 1024 * 8) / (1.073741824 * duration)

    # Target audio bitrate, in bps
    if 10 * audio_bitrate > target_total_bitrate:
        audio_bitrate = target_total_bitrate / 10
        if audio_bitrate < min_audio_bitrate < target_total_bitrate:
            audio_bitrate = min_audio_bitrate
        elif audio_bitrate > max_audio_bitrate:
            audio_bitrate = max_audio_bitrate
    # Target video bitrate, in bps.
    video_bitrate = target_total_bitrate - audio_bitrate

    i = ffmpeg.input(video_full_path)
    ffmpeg.output(i, os.devnull,
                  **{'c:v': 'libx264', 'b:v': video_bitrate, 'pass': 1, 'f': 'mp4'}
                  ).overwrite_output().run()
    ffmpeg.output(i, output_file_name,
                  **{'c:v': 'libx264', 'b:v': video_bitrate, 'pass': 2, 'c:a': 'aac', 'b:a': audio_bitrate}
                  ).overwrite_output().run()

# Compress input.mp4 to 50MB and save as output.mp4
compress_video('input.mp4', 'output.mp4', 50 * 1000)
```

### Notes

1. Don't waste your time! Judge the file size before compressing.
2. You can disable two-pass function by only keeping second `ffmpeg.output()` without parameter `'pass': 2`.
3. If video bit rate < 1000, it will throw exception `Bitrate is extremely low`.
4. The biggest min file size I recommend is:

```py
# Best min size, in kB.
best_min_size = (32000 + 100000) * (1.073741824 * duration) / (8 * 1024)
```

5. If you specify a extremely small target file size, the size of generated file maybe exceed it. For most time, this will not happen.

Comment: How do you do the same with audio files?

Comment: @MmBaguette Perhaps, this deserves a new question. There are 2 solutions. 1) Convert your audio file to video by ffmpeg, and use this snippet directly. 2) Only pass `audio_bitrate` when running `ffmpeg.output`. Like `ffmpeg.output(i, output_file_name, **{'b:a': audio_bitrate, 'f': 'mp3'}).overwrite_output().run()`.

Comment: Hello, I'm Getting the Following Error even after specifying the whole path of the input and output video file:
`
    p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "D:\Coding\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "D:\Coding\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
`

Comment: @Dhruv-2676 It looks like you do not have ffmpeg installed, do you?

Comment: I Think I Downloaded It Properly, If You Have Any Idea For Checking It, Please Tell Me...

Comment: @Dhruv-2676 Did you have the same error as [this issue](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/issues/251#issuecomment-529064124)?

Comment: @Dhruv-2676 In `ffmpeg.probe(...)` you need to give the argument `cmd="path/to/ffprobe.exe"` and in `.run(...)` you need to give `cmd="path/to/ffmpeg.exe"`.

Comment: I'm facing Error while getting media from postman and passing in to it ```subprocess.run(f'ffmpeg -i {media} -vcodec h264 -acodec mp2 temp_location/{new_uuid}')``` *Error is :* ```wa.mp4: No such file or directory```

Comment: @MdHassan413 looks like a path problem, are you sure there is a `wa.mp4`?

Comment: Actually, media coming from Postman so I think there is no path for that `{media}` it is media directly...
-*Q .* Can I store media without an extension like `wa` only?

Comment: @MdHassan413 Because we have to extract some information from the video, we must first download it locally...

Comment: OK, So if I wanted to store without an extension like `wa` only? 
I had tried to do it but was not able to store it without an extension also used `-f` and this is not working.

Comment: @MdHassan413 Yes, you should use `-f` to specify the type. You can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869120/ffmpeg-output-file-format-with-no-extension

Answer (score 1):

I have used [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/index.html) in the past with good results.
Another option (not the safest) might be to run FFMpeg as an external process to compress or resize the media file.