# ffmpeg stream Windows 7 desktop to Youtube give invalid argument

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, desktop

I am experimenting with live streaming my Windows 7 desktop to YouTube.

Firstly the list of devices:

`ffmpeg-N-100616-gca21cb1e36-win64-gpl\bin\ffmpeg.exe -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy`

Gives:

```
ffmpeg version N-100616-gca21cb1e36 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3-win32 (GCC) 20200320
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --a
rch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv
--enable-zlib --enable-libxml2 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-open
cl --enable-libvmaf --disable-vulkan --enable-libvorbis --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-li
bdavs2 --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --disable-libglslang --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-li
bopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --en
able-libopenjpeg --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-
libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-li
bxvid --enable-libzimg --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-libs=-lgomp
  libavutil      56. 63.100 / 56. 63.100
  libavcodec     58.116.100 / 58.116.100
  libavformat    58. 65.101 / 58. 65.101
  libavdevice    58. 11.103 / 58. 11.103
  libavfilter     7. 95.100 /  7. 95.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
[dshow @ 000000000052ca00] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
[dshow @ 000000000052ca00]  "VF0700 Live! Cam Chat HD"
[dshow @ 000000000052ca00]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_041e&pid_4088&mi_00#7&b015b04&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3
b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
[dshow @ 000000000052ca00]  "UScreenCapture"
[dshow @ 000000000052ca00]     Alternative name "@device_sw_{860BB310-5D01-11D0-BD3B-00A0C911CE86}\UScreenCapture"
[dshow @ 000000000052ca00]  "screen-capture-recorder"
[dshow @ 000000000052ca00]     Alternative name "@device_sw_{860BB310-5D01-11D0-BD3B-00A0C911CE86}\{4EA69364-2C8A-4AE6-A561-56E4B504
4439}"
[dshow @ 000000000052ca00] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 000000000052ca00]  "Microphone (VF0700 Live! Cam Ch"
[dshow @ 000000000052ca00]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\Microphone (VF0700 Live! Cam Ch"
[dshow @ 000000000052ca00]  "virtual-audio-capturer"
[dshow @ 000000000052ca00]     Alternative name "@device_sw_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\{8E146464-DB61-4309-AFA1-3578E927
E935}"
dummy: Immediate exit requested
```

`ffmpeg-N-100616-gca21cb1e36-win64-gpl\bin\ffmpeg.exe -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy`

gives:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1-2021-01-01-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enab
le-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libss
h --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-li
brav1e --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --en
able-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-
amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libm
fx --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-
libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb
--enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable
-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[dshow @ 0000000000485ac0] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
[dshow @ 0000000000485ac0]  "VF0700 Live! Cam Chat HD"
[dshow @ 0000000000485ac0]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_041e&pid_4088&mi_00#7&b015b04&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3
b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
[dshow @ 0000000000485ac0]  "UScreenCapture"
[dshow @ 0000000000485ac0]     Alternative name "@device_sw_{860BB310-5D01-11D0-BD3B-00A0C911CE86}\UScreenCapture"
[dshow @ 0000000000485ac0]  "screen-capture-recorder"
[dshow @ 0000000000485ac0]     Alternative name "@device_sw_{860BB310-5D01-11D0-BD3B-00A0C911CE86}\{4EA69364-2C8A-4AE6-A561-56E4B504
4439}"
[dshow @ 0000000000485ac0] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 0000000000485ac0]  "Microphone (VF0700 Live! Cam Ch"
[dshow @ 0000000000485ac0]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\Microphone (VF0700 Live! Cam Ch"
[dshow @ 0000000000485ac0]  "virtual-audio-capturer"
[dshow @ 0000000000485ac0]     Alternative name "@device_sw_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\{8E146464-DB61-4309-AFA1-3578E927
E935}"
dummy: Immediate exit requested
```

Now trying to live stream with the command:

`ffmpeg-N-100616-gca21cb1e36-win64-gpl\bin\ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -i video='screen-capture-recorder':audio='Microphone (VF0700 Live! Cam Ch' -r 24 -s 1920x1080 -qmin 3 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com:1935/live2/the-stream-key'`

I get:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1-2021-01-01-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enab
le-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libss
h --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-li
brav1e --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --en
able-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-
amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libm
fx --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-
libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb
--enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable
-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
leaving aero onGuessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=screen-capture-recorder:audio=Microphone (VF0700 Live! Cam Ch':
  Duration: N/A, start: 758394.360000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, bgr0, 1920x1080, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
[NULL @ 00000000006645c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com:1935/live2/the-stream-key
'
rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com:1935/live2/the-stream-key: Invalid argument
[dshow @ 0000000000607400] real-time buffer [screen-capture-recorder] [video input] too full or near too full (545% of size: 3041280
 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
    Last message repeated 5 times
```

In short the errors are:

```
[NULL @ 00000000006645c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com:1935/live2/the-stream-key
'
rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com:1935/live2/the-stream-key: Invalid argument
[dshow @ 0000000000607400] real-time buffer [screen-capture-recorder] [video input] too full or near too full (545% of size: 3041280
```

I have tried with and without the `:1935` port number, with `ffmpeg_x64.exe` but no difference. Is the stream key the `invalid argument` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with. The `-f` parameter is used to specif the input format `dshow`, but this parameter is also positionally dependent appliying to the input and/or output format if placed before the input and ouitput.

So the solution was to add the `-f flv` to the output as well:

`ffmpeg-N-100616-gca21cb1e36-win64-gpl\bin\ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -i video='screen-capture-recorder':audio='Microphone (VF0700 Live! Cam Ch' -r 24 -s 1920x1080 -qmin 3 -f flv 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com:1935/live2/the-stream-key'`

So, we are saying the input format is `dshow` by placing it before the `-i` flag, and the output is `flv` by placing it before the output (the stream channel).

Comment: Set frame rate via dshow with the `-framerate` dshow input option. Otherwise it will choose the default dshow input frame rate of 30, then convert to 24. Default encoder for FLV output is the old legacy flv1, which you probably don't want: add `-c:v libx264`. See [FFmpeg Wiki: YouTube](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites) for more suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. Will take a look.